# FTP Mirroring with Codeigniter creates folder, but no files uploaded

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

I am using Codeigniter to backup mysql tables and write the sql file to the local webserver's htdocs/application/backups directory.

**I want that directory to be mirrored on my remote webserver** (dreamhost backups user account) **but it's not working**, I'm not seeing the sql files in the remote directory.

I'm using CI's FTP library and it's `mirror()` function to copy the contents of my local backups directory to my remote server.

*In my database backup model I set variables to use in the scrip:*

```
private $local_folder = 'my_directory/';
private $server_folder = 'my_server_directory/';
private $server_credentials = array(
    'hostname'=>'my.hostname.com',
    'username'=>'my_username',
    'password'=>'my_password'
    );
```

*Also in the database backup model I have the mirror function:*

```
function mirror(){
    $this->load->library('ftp');
    $this->ftp->connect($this->server_credentials);
    $result = $this->ftp->mirror($this->local_folder,$this->server_folder);
    var_dump($result); //shows "true" 
    $this->ftp->close();
}
```

*I call the `mirror()` from my backup function.*  The sql files are created and stored locally by the backup function, but the local folder isn't mirrored to the webserver.

the remote backup directory permissions are '777' and test runs of `$this->ftp->list_files` and `$this->ftp->mkdir()` work just fine.

**Any ideas why files won't be uploaded?**

Comment: Are directories correct? Tryfull server directory like `/www/my_directory/` or something like that

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting an answer to my own question because the problem was my own ignorance.

`private $server_folder = 'my_server_directory/';`

should have been

`private $server_folder = '/my_server_directory/';`

I swear I tried that syntax while trouble shooting my problem, but I must have changed something else too that broke the mirroring at the same time, hiding the answer from me.

Thanks for your comments and answers @Damien Pirsy and @ Edinho Almeida.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
$this->ftp->mkdir()
```

works fine, I'm sure that your permission settings are ok.

If

```
$this->ftp->list_files()
```

works fine, I'm sure that your connection settings are ok too.

I guess your SQL backup files are starting with dot

See in

```
system/libraries/Ftp.php at lines 547 and 551
```